# .htaccess RewriteRule for directory

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to use the RewriteRule for the following

```
www.mysite.com/xyz
or
www.mysite.com/xyz/
```

==> should go to www.mysite.com/page.php?var=xyz

```
www.mysite.com/xyz.html
www.mysite.com/xyz.htm
www.mysite.com/xyz.php
or any other extension
```

==> should not be rewritten

Only when there's no file extension, the rewrite rule should be used
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ /page.php?var=$1 [L,QSA]
```