# RewriteRule Apache - Redirect only for directory, not for files within it

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I believe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23230032/htaccess-rewriterule-for-directory) may be close but I'm very new to mod_rewrite so forgive me if this is elementary.

I need to redirect requests to a particular folder and it's default page ONLY, allowing all other requests to continue as specified.  For example:

Only these urls should be rewritten:

```
http://example.com/abc
http://example.com/abc/
http://example.com/abc/index.html
```

...let's say to http://example.org

...but, the following requests should be permitted:

```
http://example.com/abc/anotherpage.html
http://example.com/abc/subdir
http://example.com/abc/subdir/
http://example.com/abc/subdir/index.html
```

I tried the following...

```
RewriteRule ^/abc/ http://example.org/ 
RewriteRule ^/abc/index.html http://example.org/
```

... but the first rewrite behaves recursively and redirects anything below abc.

Can a redirect be achieved only for a folder and not its contents (except for files specified)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a `$` delimiter at the end of your regex to indicate that it is the *end* of the match:

```
RewriteRule ^/abc/$ http://example.org/ 
RewriteRule ^/abc/index.html$ http://example.org/
```

You could alternatively combine the two into just:

```
RewriteRule ^/?abc/(?:index\.html|)$ http://example.org/ [L,R]
```

or using mod_alias instead of mod_rewrite:

```
RedirectMatch ^/abc/(?:index\.html|)$ http://example.org/
```

With the `$`, something like `/abc/123` **won't** match because the regex says that the `/` must be at the *end*.

Comment: Thanks much for your input.  I have an existing RewriteCond so the multiple rules make that easier for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/abc/index.html [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/abc$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/abc/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://your.domain/ [L,R]
```