# .htaccess RewriteRule for navigation

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, http-redirect

I need to redirect

```
www.monsite.fr/css
```

to

```
www.monsite.fr/index.php?p=css
```

in .Htaccess

I tried lots of answers found on the site without success like this one: [.htaccess RewriteRule for directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23230032/htaccess-rewriterule-for-directory/69092687#69092687)

I tried with on an other site to make regex, but once tested it doesn't work

exemples:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?p=$1 [L]
RewriteRule \/([^\/]*)$ /index.php?p=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ /index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

but none works.

I used a site that tells me these rules do what I want :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

but finally I was redirect to

```
www.monsite.fr/css/?p=css
```

what 's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#if file exist, serve the file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1&n=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

this solution seems to work.
it is necessary to put the rule which checks the existence of the file before the redirection so that the request towards the css file is not redirected.

Answer (score 0):

by dint of searching, I found this answer that does the job:

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

but i seem to have a css problem then.
the style.css file seems to be treated as an HTML file and I don't understand why